# toad for oracle autocomplete dropdown

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

Toad for Oracle has an autocomplete feature.. you type `SELECT * FROM USER.` and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> and a drop down appears where you can choose from the objects available to you.

This functionality suddenly stopped. Now, instead of a drop down, it goes to the first default match. I have no idea what I did to change the behavior.

How do I restore the drop down functionality?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In newer version of Toad, this option is under View -> Toad Options -> Editor -> Code Assist.

In older versions, this option is under Options -> Editor -> Code Assist.

The only time I have ever seen it autofill instead of providing a list is when there is only one table that matches though...  What version of Toad are you using?

Comment: There are no Options in the menubar.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it was caused by a corrupt configuration file - try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20966588/1023095) and see if it works.