# Toad: Table Autocomplete Functionality Not Working

Tags: sql, oracle, autocomplete, toad, code-assist

I've been using Toad for more than a year now without problems. All of a sudden the table autocomplete feature has ceased working. No settings have been changed, and I've clean installed a new TOAD version, yet the problem persists.

The image below shows autocomplete defaulting into view IN_INSTRUMENT in schema MCDM. Normal behaviour should result in a table/view list.

[image]

It is notable that the above does not happen with all schemas. For some schemas I will still see a table list. In the beginning this error happened only with a single schema. Now it is slowly progressing to other schemas as well, which is exceptionally frustrtating when you're dealing with dozens of schemas that contain hundreds of tables each. It slows down development when you must open Schema Browser and look for the exact table/view/procedure/package each time instead of letting autocomplete give suggestions.

This same issue has been described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161110/how-to-turn-on-table-name-autocomplete-feature-in-toad) and [and this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535428/toad-for-oracle-autocomplete-dropdown/4556488) with less detail, yet no accepted answer has been given.

As can be seen from Code Assist settings, these should be in order.

[image]

How to reset autocomplete behaviour into what is its original state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution to this problem. The issue was a corrupt configuration file. For anyone else with the same problem, this is how I fixed mine:

1. Backup your *appdata* folder - you can find its location in *options -> general -> application data*.
2. Create a new set of user files using *Utilities -> Copy User Settings -> Create clean set of user files*. Make sure you are running Toad with administrator rights.

Note that the above will delete all your saved connection details (schema names, passwords, connection strings), so take a note of these.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: I faced a similar problem. In my case, the reinstall made it works, but probably by this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Under View > Toad Options > Editor > Code Assist > Toad Insight Objects, checking Synonyms (in addition to Public Synonyms) worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me too. However problem reappears whenever our system gets an update or when a maintenance runs on the VMs. I am guessing that somehow system maintenance routine reverts the configuration file of TOAD.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check "Public synonyms" in the "Toad insight objects".

Comment: Public synonyms is checked. Tried to uncheck it, same issue. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Toad Options, and then Editor > Code Assist and uncheck "Cache Code Insight results". This made it immediately start working for me using Toad for Oracle version 9.7. I could then go back and check the box and it would still work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem even though I set up everything mentioned above. 
So basically Toad does not suggest column names if I don't define the scheme name.

```
X(schema).TABLE_NAME.(then lists all columns)
```

Worked for me..